# Hibernate performance: the same base class for a lot of children

Tags: mysql, oracle, hibernate

I have a lot of classes C1, C2, .., Cn (n~100). Each class have references to other classes (children). But one class could be referenced in different classes (child could have parents of different types). For example, C1 could have the following children: C2, C3, C4. But C2 could also be a child of C4.

```
class C1 extends AbstractEntity{
   C2 c2;
   C3 c3;
   C4 c4;
}

class C4 extends AbstractEntity {
   C2 c2;
   C5 c5;
}
```

Having an entity, I want to get its parent. So I create AbstractEntity class

```
class abstract AbstractEntity{
   Long id;
   AbstractEntity parent;
}
```

When I'm using JPA annotations in Hibernate to persist objects to the database. So I get the following AbstractEntity table:

```
table AbstractEntity (id long primary key, parent_id long foreign key references AbstractEntity(id), discriminator varchar(40));
```

Now to perform any operation with concrete entity (add, update, delete) the join with AbstractEntity would be performed. For each operation! So all operations would require access to the same table. How this will influence the performance? Would this allow me to perform operations on different resource types simultaneously, would not they block?

I understand that not the whole table is locked during the transaction and this is heavily depends on DBMS that is used. But in general, probably its better to consider the way of getting rid of common super class for a bulk of child classes when using hibernate? If DBMS really matters let it be MySQL and Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

operations on different subclasses will not block each other. hibernate will not block the table on its own. The easiest way to see if performance is good enough is to try it.